# how to execute event only on server from which is event called discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

i have my bot on 2 servers, and once I want to count all members from 1 server he counts from both servers. Lets server 1 has 2 members, and server 2 has 3 members, result is 5 instead of 2(if i want to see how many members i have on server 1)

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!count'):
        pom=0
        for guild in client.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                pom = pom + 1
        await message.channel.send("Number of people on server: " + str(pom))
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have so far

Comment: This is a theoretical question, to see how to separate the servers, that the script does not read all the servers on which the bot is located, but only the one from which the command was entered.

Comment: You can check `ctx.guild`, which will be the guild/server the command was called from. If you want a detailed answer, please update your question to include code.

Comment: @Benjin

For example this code returns number of all members of all serveres where my bot is. But I want to return number of members from servere where this command was executed.

`@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.content.startswith('!count'):
        pom=0
        for guild in client.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                pom = pom + 1
        await message.channel.send("Number of people on server: " + str(pom))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are in the `on_message` event, you can use [`message.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.guild).

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!count'):
        pom = len(message.guild.members)
        await message.channel.send("Number of people on server: " + str(pom))
```

Comment: This works. How does he knows now that he needs to give len of that specific guild?
Can you refer me some link where can I learn more about?

Comment: The `on_message` event triggers for every message sent and will pass a `message` object through the event function. This object contains everything about the message, including which guild/server it was sent to.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're either getting the total member count either with bot.users, 
or the sum of all members for each guild in the bot.guilds list. That would, of course, give you the total sum of members that the bot can see. Instead what you're looking for is to:

1. Pick one guild object, let's say ctx.guild (the guild the command was used in)
2. Use its member_count attribute, which will be the total number of members in that guild.

You'll be left with the line **ctx.guild.member_count**, and if you're in the guild that has three members, that will be 3.